# Replacing single tile before grouting

Tags: tile

I installed porcelain tile on my bathroom floor but just noticed the next day that one tile at the entrance is slightly not level with the tile beside it.

It’s not super noticeable unless you bend down and feel it but I’m more concerned it may cause issues when installing the transition in the door frame going from bathroom floor to hallway flooring.

Based on the picture is it worth removing this tile, reapplying adhesive and replacing with a new tile? Or can I just move on and grout the floor and live with it?[image]

Comment: Walk on it without shoes, if no difference, can usually sand/shave/grind the underneath of transition if needed.  If you can feel the difference, might want to replace now before it bugs you after.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Good thinking on sanding down the transition. I’ll walk on it first and decide but yes I wanted to make that call before doing the grout.

Comment: I'd add to that, slide your feet over it, tilted down, toes first - to see if it's going to be a constant 2am toe-stubber. Murphy's law says if you can catch your toe on it one time in ten intentionally, you'll do it every night once you meet it in the dark.

Comment: Looks like rectified tile so once grouted it may be more noticeable.

Comment: With care you may be able to remove it and add more adhesive to level it out.

Comment: You should definitely pop it out and redo. You have noticed it now, if you don't redo it, it is going to bug you forever that you didn't just go ahead and fix it now.

Answer (score 2):

If it's only been a day you might be able to pop the new tile out without breaking it.

Either way, I'd go with replacement. That appears to be 1/3 the thickness of the tile.